# How to secure private routes in SPA while using httpOnly cookies

Tags: authentication, cookies, local-storage, jwt, httponly

I'd like to secure my SPA private routes with JWT authentication. To make everything as much secure as it's possible, I wanted to use `httpOnly` cookie to store my `access_token` on the client-side.

Using `httpOnly` cookies protect me a lot from XSS attacks, but unfortunately this approach does not allow me to check if the cookie actually exists in the browser.

**In this case - how can I implement some logic to prevent unlogged users to visit private, secure routes of my SPA?**

Am I forced to use non-`httpOnly` cookies or `localStorage` for this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Am I forced to use non-httpOnly cookies or localStorage for this?

No. Keep your `access_token` in a cookie with the `httpOnly` flag, and (if possible) with the `secure` flag.
Let's call this cookie `session_cookie`.

When a user does a successful login you could return 2 cookies: the `session_cookie` and another one which informs to JS the user has been authenticated (let's call as `SPA cookie`).

Your `session_cookie` is not accessible by `JS` so it's not vulnerable to `XSS`. This cookie is sent on each request to the server, which checks is a valid token, otherwise an unauthorized error is returned.

Your `SPA cookie` hasn't `httpOnly` flag so it's accessible by `JS` but the server doesn't use it to authenticate the user, so fake this cookie is useless.

Whenever you receive an unauthorized error on your `SPA` you can remove the `SPA cookie`.

Comment: I like the idea. Thanks :)

Comment: I know that a causal user will be unable to access the secure pages, but this does not prevent a user from adding the 'SPA cookie' manually and accessing the secure pages.

Comment: This isn't to prevent users from manually including cookies. It's to prevent JS code from accessing cookies.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. A user manually updates spa cookie, he  can access other routes in this SPA, But he could not make any API call from it(as long as the http cookie is expired or cleared)

Comment: That is correct @Abel