.NET 8 Authentication & Authorization with SPA
I started developing a simple CMS project with an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and created a Vite + ReactJS + TypeScript SPA project as frontend.
I created basic JWT authentication without using ASP.NET Core Identity.
I'm a bit new to those frontend technologies. I've lost myself when searching for token security vulnerabilities and how to implement authentication on the SPA side. A lot of resources say, to store the token in localStorage but this is not the secure way I believe. On the other hand, the backend can set this token to a cookie with the HttpOnly flag and I guess this is the acceptable way besides localStorage.
But, the cookie can not be accessible by the client side by Javascript. So, how can I understand if the user is authenticated or not in the SPA project?
The backend can respond with another token for SPA in the body (not JWT) and the SPA can understand user is authenticated (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965652/5440386).
But I guess this is not the best practice and the topic is so old. So, I need the help here.
Let's say we move that way, and I put the token in the localStorage;

Should I ask the server is user valid or not in every page refresh (using HTTP-only cookie)?
Can I use Redux instead of localStorage and how do I prevent the session from being closed on every page refresh? Is it good practice?
Are there any other vulnerabilities I should be aware of?

Also, I want to add custom role-based authorization in the future. If the user does not have permission, I will hide the menus, buttons, and routes in the SPA project. What is the best practice here and how should it be implemented? Like, should I return the roles in the login response body? etc.
Thanks in advance.
